# Advice on starting off to solve Job shop scheduling

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, job-scheduling

I need to create  program where there are 14 jobs but 2 machines. 
The oven can handle 4 of the jobs at a time but the autoclave can handle 2.

Could someone please advice on how I should approach coding this problem? My apologies as I am still new to python and unsure how to approach the problem.

```
 I have formatted it as: (machine number, time it takes to finish the task 
 on the machine)
 In this case, I have used 0 for oven and 1 for autoclave

Job 1:[(0,720),(0,180), (1,330)]
Job 2:[(0,720),(1,180), (1,330)]
Job 4:[(0,720),(0,1440)]
Job 5:[(0,720),(0,180),(0,60)]
Job 7:[(0,720),(0,60)]
Job 8:[(0,720),(0,160),(1,330)]
Job 10:[(0,720),(0,90),(0,90)]
Job 12:[(0,720),(0,120)]
Job 13:[(0,720),(1,330)]
Job 16:[(0,720),(0,960)]
Job 17:[(0,720),(0,90),(0,90),(0,90)]
Job 19:[(0,720),(0,100)]
Job 26:[(0,720),(0,150)]
Job 27:[(0,720),(0,150)]
```

Comment: What kind of jobs are there? Are there 4 specific jobs of the 14 that the oven can handle, and respectively 2 specific autoclave jobs? Or are there 14 arbitrary tasks any machine can complete? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just wanting to look into a program that could possible efficiently schedule on what items can be fed in the oven and autoclave at a given time. The 14 jobs all need to go through the oven but only 4 of them go through the autoclave (those that go through the autoclave have to go through the oven first). And majority of the 14 jobs need to go in the oven more than once with an idle time in between

Comment: Perhaps write out what each job requires first. Which machine is needed in what order with what minimum/maximum time between each step. You can then go about trying to minimize the wait times. I'm afraid without more concrete information that's all the suggestions I can make.

Comment: @JLossner let me just quickly put up a list that I have made so far

Comment: @JLossner Those are kind of the sequence task I have listed for each of the jobs

Comment: Alright, that helps a little. But what are you trying to achieve with the jobs? Do they all have to run an equal amount of times, in as little time as possible / continuously? Is there an order that needs to be maintained?

Comment: @JLossner They just have to go through the oven and then autoclave, the jobs themselves don't have to go in any particular order. The jobs aren't to be done every and would depend on what is given on the day, so I was thinking on some days the time would just be changed to zero (i.e say if Job 1, 12, 16 and 17 don't need to be done for that day).

Comment: @JLossner I was thinking something along the lines of  that the oven and the autoclave would be occupied as much as they can for a day instead of having more idle time than there needs to be

Comment: @JLossner sorry as I don't have enough reputation to chat yet

Comment: Okay, I would suggest prioritizing pending jobs based on next task duration, total duration remaining, and idle time. If you want to make sure the autoclave is occupied as much as possible, maybe add a higher priority for jobs that have upcoming autoclave tasks, so they get moved through the oven sooner and can "wait" for the autoclave. Then just have the machines fish the highest priority jobs out of their respective pending pools. Is that the kind of advice you were looking for?

Comment: @JLossner could I possibly ask as to how I should start coding for this? i.e. using the travelling postman problem/ job shop scheduling?

Comment: I would probably write a Job class with the tasks and priority function (including idle time), then optimize the weighting of the individual times considered for priority, using the idle time of oven and autoclave as a cost function to minimize. However you would probably have to redo the optimization whenever the jobs for a given day change, so there is probably a better solution out there.

Comment: Which kind of method are you looking to solve the problem? Dispatching rules? Metaheuristics?

Comment: @WillEnsaba https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/job_shop I'm looking at this one that I saw from google. However, I am unsure if this would be the best approach to use for this problem.

Comment: @CodeIt I am now reinstalling it and have checked the box for Path

Comment: @ElizabethDC IBM ILOG CP Optimizer. They have the code for the JSP in their repository. The state-of-the-art exact algorithm for JSP is the iSTS-SGS. It is a two-phase hybridization of a JSP-specific tabu search (iSTS) with a specialized CP search (SGS). Check [1] or [2] for more informations. [1] Mixed Integer Programming Models for Job Shop Scheduling: a Computational Analysis”. Computers & Operations Research. 2016. [2] J. C. Beck, T. Feng, J. P. Watson, Combining constraint programming and local search for job-shop scheduling, INFORMS Journal on Computing 23 (1) (2011) 1–14.